# Can I resize an swf object that is coming from an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash, iframe

I was wondering if is possible to resize an embedded swf object that is being display on a website from a remote location via iframe?

```
    <style>
embed {
position: relative;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
</style>

<div id="myContainer" style="border: 0px solid rgb(201, 0, 1); overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 2236px; max-height: 836px;">
<iframe scrolling="no" src="http://schools.nyc.gov" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: -233px; height: 479px; margin-top: -152px; width: 747px; " >
</iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I found a way. Stream that code from another iframe.

```
<style>
 body {
   transform: scale(2.4);
   transform-origin: 0 0;
   // add prefixed versions too.
}
</style>
<div id="myContainer" style="border: 0px solid rgb(201, 0, 1); overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 2236px; max-height: 836px;">
<iframe scrolling="no" src="http://schools.nyc.gov" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: -233px; height: 479px; margin-top: -152px; width: 747px; " >
</iframe>
</div>
```